# Wire adpater data / need to iterate through object if I receive always only one record?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm wondering if there is a better way because I the received data contains always only one record. But I found no other way than to iterate in the html doc in order to get the values. Do you have any ideas about this - would be great.

And a minor but nasty other thing: the `lightning-formatted-rich-text` seems not working if I paste the values as below despite the `includedServices` is a richtext field!?

Thank you!
Maserick

```
//tripIncludedServices.js

import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";

import initMethod from "@salesforce/apex/MCWrapperController.initMethod";

export default class tripIncludedServices extends LightningElement {
results;

  @wire(initMethod, { cmsContentType: 'cms_includedServices'}) 
  
  wiredContent ({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      // const cmstitle = cmsIncludesServices.contenNodes.title.value;
      this.results = data;
      console.log ('cms', this.results);
     } else if (error) {
      // handle error
    }
  }
}
```

```
<template>
    <lightning-layout title="Inklusiv-Reiseleistungen">
        <template if:true={results}>
            <template for:each={results} for:item="result">
            <lightning-layout-item size=12 padding="around-small" key={contentKey}>
                <h1>{result.contentNodes.title.value}</h1>
                <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={result.contentNodes.includedServices.value}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
                <span> {result.contentNodes.price.value}</span>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
        </template>
    </lightning-layout>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just take out the first element:

```
  this.results = data[0];
```

Or you could fix your Apex code so it only returns one record, presuming only one is ever returned:

```
public with sharing class MCWrapperController {
 // Replace sObject with correct data type, below
 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true) public static sObject initMethod(String cmsContentType) {
    // ...
```

Comment: hey @sfdcfox, easy if you know it ;-) your feedback is so great - many thanks!! btw: any idea why  ´lightning-formatted-rich-text´ is showing '<ul> <li>8-t&auml;gige Flugreise nach Madeira ins 5* Meli&aacute; Madeira Mare</li> </ul>` instead of the correct formatting?

Comment: @Maserick It sounds like it's "double-escaped", presumably because of the Apex code that you haven't specified. You could use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to unescape the characters, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/2132791).

Comment: this is it - yeehaa! Men, lot to learn...